# Excel Export functionality in Kendo grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-mvvm

I was trying to export a hierarchical grid to excel. Just wanted to confirm if this is possible. Currently I was only able to export the parent grid. Please find the jsbin that I created for the issue [here](http://jsbin.com/budesutuso/1/edit?html,output).

Answer (score 2):

It's a little bit of work, but there's an example in the [docs](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/grid/how-to/excel/detail-grid-export)

Answer (score 0):

I am attempting to get this working as well. In order to get the detail grids, they must be expanded. I am doing it this way, although it contains the correct data in hierarchical form, it is generating .xls file for each row! Maybe you can tweak? The exportGrid function is pulled from docs at link posted by Joe:

```
if (grid.options.excel.allPages) {
    originalPageSize = grid.dataSource.pageSize();
    originalHandler = grid.options.dataBound.name;

    //show all
    grid.dataSource.pageSize(grid.pager.dataSource._total);
    grid.bind('dataBound', function (e) {
        //expand all
        toggleDetailGridRows('expand', $(grid.element).attr('id'));
        grid.bind('dataBound', originalHandler);
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        ExcelHelper.exportGrid(e, grid);
        grid.dataSource.pageSize(originalPageSize);
    }, 2000);    
}
else {
    ExcelHelper.exportGrid(e, grid);
}
```